# Error whilst sending email via Mandrill extension on Wordpress / Civi 4.7alpha5

Tags: civimail, mandrill

When attempting to send an email to event participants (via participant listing > action > send email), I receive the following error:

> Cannot read unrecognized property CRM_Core_Config::$civiVersion.

Upon trying to send to them as a group via CiviMail, I also get the same error in my process_mailing log

Any advice on how to resolve this would be appreciated!

Running CiviCRM 4.7alpha5 on Wordpress 4.3.1 with Mandrill and Clickatell extensions installed

Comment: Does turning off the extensions make any difference?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, must've disengaged my brain yesterday. Disabled the mandrill extension and I now have mail again!

Comment: Just to flag it here, there is a new version of the Mandrill extension coming soon: https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.mte/issues/100

Answer (score 3):

JMA will be releasing a version of the extension that works with 4.7 in the first week of February. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an unreleased version where you can expect a few bugs. So I guess you ran into one.

You would help the developers if you add this bug to the issue tracking system of CiviCRM at https://issues.civicrm.org